# Запустить .exe файлы c++

Tags: c++, windows, файлы

Подскажите, пожалуйста.Мне нужно создать 2 exe-файла: **test1.exe** и **test2.exe.** кладем в разные папки, пусть первый кладем в `c:\home\test1.exe` а второй в `c:\work\test2.exe`. пишем два текстовых файла:

```
test1.txt:
c:\home\test1.exe
c:\work\test2.exe
test2.txt:
c:\work\test2.exe
c:\home\test1.exe
```

затем пишем программу **prog.exe** которая принимает аргументом путь к одному из двух текстовых файлов. результаты работы такие:

```
prog.exe test1.txt: запуск сначала test1, затем test2
prog.exe test2.txt: запуск сначала test2, затем test1
```

Вопрос, как запустить `.exe` файлы с прочитанного текстового файла?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <process.h>


using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    cout << "argc = " << argc << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        cout << "Argument: " << i << " = " << argv[i] << endl;
    }

    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    char ch;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(argv[1]);
    if (!infile) {
        cout << "errrrror: cant open a file" << argv[1];
        exit(-1);
    }
    while (infile) {
        infile.get(ch);
        cout << ch;
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего - `system`.

Сложнее - `spawn...`.

Еще сложнее - использовать Windows API, типа `CreateProcess`.

Если я верно понял задаваемый вопрос, конечно...

P.S. Под сложнее одновременно имеется в виду "зато больше возможностей" :)

Comment: подскажите , пожалуйста , как правильно использовать system ?

Comment: Ему надо передать строку, как если бы вы набирали ее в системном приглашении...

Comment: @NikitaGusev как-то так: `system("run_file.exe")`

Comment: @Harry а чем плох system? Что вы отранжировали простое решение - сложное.

Comment: @pavel Ну, потому что при этом создается лишний сеанс оболочки - а оно надо? например, будет не очень хорошо, если оттуда запускается GUI-приложение. Да и возможностей управления - почти никаких, как и проверки - запустилось или нет...

Answer (score -2):

Если тебе <s>не противно обмазываться</s> не нужна кроссплаторменость, то можно использовать .Net класс [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
#using <System.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;

Process^ myProcess = gcnew Process();
myProcess->StartInfo->FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice 5\\program\\soffice.exe";
myProcess->Start();
```

Можно так же попробовать [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx)

```
#include <Windows.h>
LPCTSTR path = L"C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice 5\\program\\soffice.exe";
ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", path, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Comment: Большая ошибка говорить при плюсоводах о C++/CLI :)